# Increase display font size in react quill

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, react-quill

I want to increase the inner text size of react quill text box, not the output text size but text editor's font size [Image of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUWNw.png)
in the image, you can see the different font sizes. It looks odd
This is code

```
"use client"

import React from 'react';
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';
import 'react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css';

const TextEditor = ({ value, onChange  }) => {
  const toolbarOptions = [
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline'],     
    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],            
    [{ 'list': 'ordered' }, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'header': [ 2, 3, false] }],
    [{ 'script': 'sub' }, { 'script': 'super' }],     
    [{ 'align': [] }],

    ['clean']                                        
  ];

  return (
    <ReactQuill
    style={{ fontSize: '20px' }}
       theme="snow"
      value={value}
      onChange={onChange}
      modules={{
        toolbar: toolbarOptions
      }}
      className="border-0 px-3 py-2 placeholder-gray-400 text-black bg-white rounded shadow focus:outline-none focus:ring w-full ease-linear transition-all duration-150"
    />
  );
};

export default TextEditor;
```

here I tried text-base text-lg but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your toolbarOptions
 `[{ size: ["small", false, "large", "huge"] }]`